# Which test to use with three variables?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, anova, data-visualization, dataset

that's my chart:

[image]

let's say that D0.5 was missing OJ. what statistical test could I use in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [One-way Anova](https://www.jmp.com/en_nl/statistics-knowledge-portal/one-way-anova.html) to compare the means of three or more variables using the function `aov`. Your outcome variable is len and the independent variable is dose. Here is the visualization:

```r
library(ggpubr)
data('ToothGrowth')

ggline(ToothGrowth, x = "dose", y = "len", color = "supp",
       add = c("mean_se", "dotplot"), palette = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"))
```

[image]

Let's test it with `aov` and check the `summary`:

```r
res.aov <- aov(len ~ dose, data = ToothGrowth)
summary(res.aov)
#>             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
#> dose         1   2224  2224.3   105.1 1.23e-14 ***
#> Residuals   58   1228    21.2                     
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

You can see that the p-value is less than 0.05, which means that there is a significant differences between the groups highlighted with `*` in the output.

---

Sources:

- [One-Way ANOVA Test in R](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/one-way-anova-test-in-r)

Comment: Isn't dose the $x$ (independent) variable and length the $y$ (outcome) variable in the ANOVA? I refer to this statement:  "Your independent variable is len and dependent variables are the groups of dose".

Comment: And this is a very pretty plot. However, judging from the labeling "dose" is actually numeric? So I'm wondering whether treating it as a factor makes sense, in either the ANOVA or the plot?

Comment: @dipetkov, Your first comment is completely right! I changed it, thanks for the suggestion!